# What would cause a dynamically loaded (long list) JQM Custom selectmenu button to reload the page?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a custom jQM select menu. When the page loads, there is one "place holder" option.

```
<select id="rfa-select-issues" data-native-menu="false" data-mini="true">
    <option data-mini="true">Select one or more</option>
</select>
```

Clicking on the SELECT button, causes expected behavior where a popup list is shown. I have some script that dynamically loads information when the user enters data in a text field.

```
$("#bws-bipad").on("change", function() {
    var value = $("#bws-bipad").val();
    if (value) {
        value = value.trim();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<c:url value="/issues/bipad/" />" + value,
        })
        .then( function ( response ) {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                $("#rfa-select-issues").empty(); 
                var html = "<option data-mini='true'>Select one or more</option>";
                $(html).appendTo("#rfa-select-issues");
                $.each( response.message, function ( i, issue ) {
                    var year = ("0000" + issue.year).slice(-4);
                    var addon = ("00" + issue.addon).slice(-2);
                    html = "<option id=" + issue.id + " data-mini='true'>" + year + " - " + addon + "</option>";
                    $(html).appendTo("#rfa-select-issues");
                });
                $("#rfa-select-issues").selectmenu('refresh', true);
            } else {
                $("#rfa-select-issues").empty(); 
                var html = "";
                $.each( response.errors, function ( code, message ) {
                    html = "<option id=" + code + " data-mini='true'>" + code + " - " + message + "</option>";
                    $(html).appendTo("#rfa-select-issues");
                });
                $("#rfa-select-issues").selectmenu('refresh', true);
            }
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
        });
    }
});
```

When it hits a response.status != 200, there is one error message loaded into the  selectmenu, and clicking on the button works as expected. When it gets a good response back (response.status == 200), there will be a long list of items put in. I have verified the s get loaded into the dom. The problem is that now when I click on the button, it pops it up in the middle of the page for a second then reloads the entire page. What can I do so that it won't reload the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is intentionally: if the resulting `listview` is higher that the window size, then JQM is automatically adding a new page which is acting as container of that long list.

IMHO people of JQM have done a great job by trying to keep compatibility and a consistent behavior across all browsers, so i feel i should just trust the default JQM behavior which has been intended for a good overall backward compatibilty, gracefully degradation, and usability also with smaller screen sizes in mobile devices.

If You don't want the default JQM behavior, you can override the internal `_decideFormat` function and do some experiment with the usability of that forced, very long, popup.

Here is a snippet:

```js
$.widget("mobile.selectmenu", $.mobile.selectmenu, {
  _decideFormat: function() {
    var self = this;
    self.menuType = "overlay";

    self.listbox.one({
      popupafteropen: $.proxy(this, "_focusMenuItem")
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-list">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h3>List Page</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="select-custom-24">Multiple, icon left, long list:</label>
        <select name="select-custom-24" id="select-custom-24" data-native-menu="false" multiple="multiple" data-iconpos="left">
          <option>Choose options</option>
          <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
          <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
          <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
          <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
          <option value="CA" selected="selected">California</option>
          <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
          <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
          <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
          <option value="FL" selected="selected">Florida</option>
          <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
          <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
          <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
          <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
          <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
          <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
          <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
          <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
          <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
          <option value="ME">Maine</option>
          <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
          <option value="MA" selected="selected">Massachusetts</option>
          <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
          <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
          <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
          <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
          <option value="MT">Montana</option>
          <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
          <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
          <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
          <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
          <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
          <option value="NY">New York</option>
          <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
          <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
          <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
          <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
          <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
          <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
          <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
          <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
          <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
          <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
          <option value="TX">Texas</option>
          <option value="UT">Utah</option>
          <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
          <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
          <option value="WA">Washington</option>
          <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
          <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
          <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
      <h3>Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As you see, the whole page beyond the `popup` is resized, and is scrolling.

Regarding the resize of the popup, there isn't an out-of-the-box solution, because you are asynchronously refreshing the content: `....then( function ( response ) ... .selectmenu('refresh'...` so this is more a workflow issue than a coding issue.